# ROSLaunch and SRC

Tags: slam, navigation, lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, I'm new to ROS.
I'm trying to understand how ROS works. I already did the tutorials but I really can't understand how does launch files works. I mean, sometimes I don't know how the launch files are connected with the logical part included in the src/ folder.

Thank you all!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270857/roslaunch-and-src/) by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2017-09-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-13**:
Welcome! I think that in order to get a better response, you should ask at least two separate questions. One about the launch files/source code connection and the other about RPLIDAR and SLAM as these are two different subjects. You can edit this question and then ask a new one as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, a *very* brief explanation of launch files and `roslaunch`. According to the [wiki entry for `roslaunch`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch):

> `roslaunch` is a tool for easily launching multiple ROS nodes locally and remotely via SSH...

Launch files provide a way, among other things, to launch a node (or nodes) with a single command:

```
roslaunch <package-name> <launch-file.launch>
```

Let's say that your package is called `my_package` with a node called `my_node` saved in the `src` folder. You can run (i.e., *launch*) your node by creating a launch file called `my_node.launch` like so:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="my_package" type="my_node" name="my_node"/>
</launch>
```

and run it using

```
roslaunch my_package my_node.launch
```

The code inside of the launch file is just XML. The `launch` tag tells ROS that this is a launch file (they don't have to have a `.launch` file extension) and the `node` tag tells `roslaunch` to run a node. Here are what the `node` tags attributes mean:

- `pkg`: the package your node is in
- `type` attribute says what the executable name is (for C++, for Python this is the filename so you would put the file extension)
- `name`: this is what you want ROS Master to call your node. This is useful for giving nodes meaningful names and using multiple instances of the same node in the same namespace.

You can also configure nodes via parameters and include launch files within launch files (within launch files...) to create a very complex system. In fact, some ROS packages can be composed of nothing but launch files from other packages!

Launch files are one of the many powerful features of ROS because they make it very easy to configure your system and they promote extensibility and resuse. There are many more features of launch files and I recommend that you read through the wiki to get a better understanding of them.

[This wiki entry for `roslaunch`](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML) does a good job of explaining the `roslaunch` XML format and the book [A Gentle Introduction to ROS](https://www.cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/) has a [chapter on how to use launch files](https://cse.sc.edu/%7Ejokane/agitr/agitr-letter-launch.pdf) as well.

---

**Edit:**

**TL;DR:**

`catkin` is used to compile the code into executables (or, for Python you `chmod +x` it) and then you tell `roslaunch` what executable to execute with the `node` tag and its attributes.

**Longer explanation:**

For the "logical" part: `roslaunch` will run exectuables from a package. It knows what executable you want to run through the `node` tag's `type` attribute. You put the executable's name as the value for `type` and `roslaunch` knows that you want to run an executable with the same name (from the package that you specified with the `pkg` attribute). This can be from C++, Python, or whatever supported language was used to write the node.

The code in the `src` folder (or wherever it is located) is not going to be executed by `roslaunch`, only executables can be run.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2017-09-14**:
Well, thanks for the whole explanation. But the thing I don't understand it's what I said "logical" part.
Most of the packages included in ROS have .cpp/.h/.py files, there you have a lot of code and I thought the launch files are executing those .cpp/.h/.py files.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2017-09-14**:
Now I get it. I didn't know about the "type". i really appreciate your help!!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-14**:
No problem, glad to help.